# NSString sizeWithFont: alternative in iOS7

Tags: ios7

The method `(sizeWithFont: forWidth: lineBreakMode:)` was deprecated in iOS 7.0.

But how can I do a same thing like following code in iOS 7.0?

```
CGSize fontSize =[self.text sizeWithFont:self.font forWidth:self.frame.size.width lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

Can `(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)` do this? I am not sure but this is the method I searched on apple document.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If you're still supporting iOS6 and not taking advantage of any new rendering features, it is fine to still use the deprecated method.  If you're only supporting iOS7, `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` is the right method to use.

Answer (score 15):

I have got a category for NSString to get the width or heigth of a string:

```c
- (CGFloat)widthWithFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    return [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:attributes] size].width;
}

- (CGFloat)heigthWithWidth:(CGFloat)width andFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
    CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: that's great, just a small error in heigthWithWidth, it's better if you remove the fixed width in the boundingRectWithSize for width parameter :)
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];

Answer (score 0):

For those who want the height with width function but in swift its:

```
func HeigthWithWidth(stringToSize : String, width : CGFloat, font : UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringToSize);
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: stringToSize.characters.count));
    var rect = attrStr.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max), options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading], context: nil);
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Hope that helps those who come looking later