# How to adjust UILabel font size to fit the fixed Rectangle (for iOS7 +)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, font-size, word-wrap

I know this question has been asked so many times and I have seen most of the solutions like
[How to adjust font size of label to fit the rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844397/how-to-adjust-font-size-of-label-to-fit-the-rectangle)

[How to calculate actual font point size in iOS 7 (not the bounding rectangle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195541/how-to-calculate-actual-font-point-size-in-ios-7-not-the-bounding-rectangle)

[NSString sizeWithFont: alternative in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010207/nsstring-sizewithfont-alternative-in-ios7)

What I want is that I want to adjust the font size in a given rect with **WORD WRAPPING** technique. The posts I mentioned above somehow adjust the font size but none of them is using word wrapping technique. Let say, I have a label

```
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 25)]; \\60px width
tempLabel.text = @"Internationalisation";
tempLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Now it should wrap the text in one line (within 60 px) with minimum possible font. But it keeps the text in 2 lines with a bit bigger font and the text breaks up like "Internationali" in first line and "sation" in second. How can we apply word wrapping in it.

```
tempLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

does not seem to work for two or more lines and

```
CGSize size = [self sizeWithFont:font 
          minFontSize:minFontSize
       actualFontSize:&actualFontSize
             forWidth:maxWidth
        lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
```

is deprecated in iOS7+
So how can I resolve my Issue. Please do help. This is so important for me.

Comment: Instead of "sizeWithFont..." method you can use "sizeWithAttributes..." method of NSString.